# change permission of file after upload iis php IIS Server

Tags: php, iis, file-upload

It may be a duplicate question(Sorry if it is really). Actually I am working with a file permission issue with IIS server and PHP.

I uploaded a PDF file and move that to upload directory successfully. But now when I given link to an uploaded file like *http://mydomain.com/application/upload/test.pdf*, it gives an `500 internal server error`.  My code exist in application directory.

I logged into server and give the upload directory and files give permissions the file downloaded.

But when I upload a new file it happened again for that file. So, how can I set the proper permission for each file I upload.

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Anybody has an answer yet? I'm experiencing the same problem and don't want to duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

After file uploading also give the uploading script permission of 755

```
chmod("/path/to/your/youruploadedfile", 755);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @NitinKumarSoni Then right click the folder select properties and change the security permissions to write all

Comment: @NitinKumarSoni I think this link will help you.http://www.victor-ratajczyk.com/post/2012/02/16/Windows-PHP-IIS-chmod-and-is_writable.aspx